# Is 猪肉饭 the actual name of a specific Chinese dish or is it merely a description of any pork-and-rice meal?

Tags: food

I know there's a dish named luroufan but in another forum (Duolingo) there's mention of "zhuroufan".

So obviously zhurou is pork and fan is rice but can also I suppose just mean "meal".

What I'm not sure about is whether this refers to a specific dish in Chinese as the names of Chinese dishes are very often quite concise or idiomatic anyway.

Comment: 猪肉饭 bkrs：there is no such word, there are 猪肉(pork) and 饭, specific dishes: 猪肉炒饭 (fried rice with pork), 咸肉猪油菜饭(search web get many hits)

Comment: It's a quite general term.

Comment: Basically, 猪肉饭 refers to any kind of dishes, made by 猪肉 + 米饭.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such word, at least few people say it, in Taiwan. However, we might call a bowl of rice and some slices of roasted pork as "燒(roasted)肉飯"、"燒肉丼(a kind of Japanese famous dishes)".

Comment: And 卤肉饭 猪脚饭 猪排饭.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it might by the only chance you can hear this word from cabin group of airplane.
In some situation, the choose of food is very limited -- like in economy class of airplane, you may only have 2 choices totally. The cabin group member may just ask such a question:
你想要猪肉饭还是鸡肉饭？你想要猪肉饭还是牛肉面？
Do you want to have pork with rice or chicken with rice? Do you want to have pork with rice or beef with noodle?

They don't need (or want) to specify the way how the pork is cooked.